# How do I get python requests package to work?

Tags: python, path, pip, python-requests, package

I can't seem to get the requests package to install correctly. Regardless of what I use to actually run my program, I get the same error:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/garce/Desktop/songlyrics/getlyrics.py", line 2, in <module> import requests ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'`

However, I've used pip to install requests. When I run `pip show requests` in a terminal window, it comes up with this:

`Name: requests Version: 2.24.0 Summary: Python HTTP for Humans. Home-page: https://requests.readthedocs.io Author: Kenneth Reitz Author-email: me@kennethreitz.org License: Apache 2.0 Location: /Users/garce/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages Requires: urllib3, idna, certifi, chardet Required-by: Sphinx, jupyterlab-server, conda, conda-build, anaconda-project, anaconda-client`

I assume this is a path issue of some sort, but I can't figure out what's going wrong here. Any idea?

Comment: Please share how (and where) are you using the pip command, and how are you running the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you installing the package globally, or within a pipenv environment? If globally, have you tried pipenv? Not only is it considered best practices, but I find that using pipenv or Anaconda environments often resolves path issues I experience.

Comment: I tried pipenv and it seemed to work!! I was a little reticent to as I've heard pipenv n00bs can screw up their computers by trying it but nothing bad has happened so far

Comment: For what it's worth, you absolutely *can* screw up your computer with pipenv. So, like, being careful. None of it is really irreversible (at least not on the Linux/Mac systems I've used, and I doubt that Windows is any different) but I can't say that I have been able to clear all my own detritus from pipenv.

Personally, I would highly recommend Anaconda, but I know this is not the popular answer and stems largely from my data science background.